# Symfony 4 Voter Verify User is Fully Authenticated

Tags: symfony, symfony4

Is there an easier way (or just better alternative) to while doing a Voter check to verify a user is actually logged in?

Example:

```
protected function voteOnAttribute($attribute, $subject, TokenInterface $token)
{
    switch ($attribute) {
        case self::VIEW:
            return $this->canView($subject, $token);
        case self::EDIT:
            return $this->canEdit($subject, $token);
        case self::CREATE:
            return $this->canCreate($token);
    }
}

/**
 * @param TokenInterface $token
 * @return bool
 */
private function canCreate(TokenInterface $token)
{
    if (!$token->getUser() instanceof User)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if ($token->getUser()->isEnabled() && !$token->getUser()->isFreeze())
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The problem I'm having is stemming from `$token->getUser()` returns a string when the user is anon. and not an actual User entity.

This is fairly easily done within the controller with `$this->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')` I just feel like I'm missing something similar that can be done within voters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can inject the AuthorizationChecker into the voter and then do the `isGranted()`-check.

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationCheckerInterface;

class MyVoter
{
    private $authChecker;

    public function __construct(AuthorizationCheckerInterface $authChecker)
    {
        $this->authChecker = $authChecker;
    }

    private function canCreate(TokenInterface $token)
    {
        if (!$this->authChecker->isGranted('IS_FULLY_AUTHENTICATED')) {
            return false;
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```